Nestjs & TypeORM: Error using TypeORM getOne but execute works
I am using multi-schema approach to manage my SaaS app in NestJS and TypeORM. Now, when I try to fetch a user using email, it fails and throws an error.
Error: TypeORMError: Cannot get entity metadata for the given alias "u"
const user = await this.entityManger.createQueryBuilder()
            .from(`${schemaName}.${UserTableName}`, 'u')
            .select(['u.id'])
            .where('u.email = :email', { email })
            .getOne()

But, surprisingly it works if I replace .getOne() with .execute(). What could be the reason for that?

what is the value for this UserTableName variable

@DileepaMabulage 'user'

@DileepaMabulage there is nothing wrong with the UserTableName or anything else but same query works with .execute()

https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/select-query-builder It seems like the execute() used for data mutations, not for data fetching
